# Не могу получить данные из базы данных

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

Пробую делать мини приложение, что-то типа доски объявлений. Ни как не получается у меня сделать поиск по фильтру. Пробовал через `CriteriaBuilder`, не получилось разобраться что там и к чему. Тогда решил сделать фильтр создавая динамический запрос в базу данных. База данных `Oracle`.
Сущность `Ad` - объявление:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AD")
public class Ad extends IdEntity{
    private Long id;
    private User user;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Integer price;
    private String city;
    private String numberPhone;
    private Date dateFrom;
    private Date dateTo;
    private CurrencyType currencyType;
    private CategoryType categoryType;
    private SubcategoryType subcategoryType;

    public Ad() {
    }

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "AD_SQ", sequenceName = "AD_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "AD_SQ")
    @Column(name = "ID_AD")
    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_USER")
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    @Column(name = "AD_NAME", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Column(name = "AD_DESCRIPTION", nullable = false)
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @Column(name = "PRICE", nullable = false)
    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @Column(name = "CITY", nullable = false)
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    @Column(name = "NUMBER_PHONE", nullable = false)
    public String getNumberPhone() {
        return numberPhone;
    }

    @Column(name = "DATE_FROM", nullable = false)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy'T'hh:mm")
    public Date getDateFrom() {
        return dateFrom;
    }

    @Column(name = "DATE_TO", nullable = false)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy'T'hh:mm")
    public Date getDateTo() {
        return dateTo;
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "CURRENCY_TYPE", nullable = false)
    public CurrencyType getCurrencyType() {
        return currencyType;
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_TYPE", nullable = false)
    public CategoryType getCategoryType() {
        return categoryType;
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "SUBCATEGORY_TYPE", nullable = false)
    public SubcategoryType getSubcategoryType() {
        return subcategoryType;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static Ad createFromJson(String jsonString){
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Ad ad = null;

        try {
            ad = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Ad.class);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ad;
    //getters and setters, equals and hash code 
    //I don’t give this data, but they exist
    }
```

`Filter`:

```
public class Filter {
    private CategoryType categoryType;
    private String city;
    private String description;

    public Filter() {
    }

    public CategoryType getCategoryType() {
        return categoryType;
    }

    public void setCategory(CategoryType categoryType) {
        this.categoryType = categoryType;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static Filter createFromJson(String jsonString){
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Filter filter = null;

        try {
            filter = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Filter.class);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringJoiner(", ", Filter.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                .add("categoryType=" + categoryType)
                .add("city='" + city + "'")
                .add("description='" + description + "'")
                .toString();
    }
}
```

Класс `AdDAO`:

```
@Repository("adDAO")
@Transactional
public class AdDAO extends GeneralDAO<Ad> {

    @SuppressWarnings("SqlResolve")
    private static final String SQL_GET_ADS_BY_CURRENT_DATE = "SELECT * FROM AD WHERE ROWNUM < 101 AND DATE_TO > ? ORDER BY DATE_TO DESC";
    private static final String SQL_GET_ADS_BY_FILTER = "SELECT * FROM AD WHERE ROWNUM < 101 AND DATE_TO > ? AND AD_DESCRIPTION LIKE ?";

    //1. получить текущую дату
    //2. сравнить в запросе текущую дату с датой объекта
    //3. если дата объекта меньше текущей даты то взять этот объект из базы данных
    //4. выводить только 100 последних объектов удовлетворяющих условию по дате
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Ad> get100Ad(){
        Date currentDate = new Date();

        NativeQuery<Ad> query = (NativeQuery<Ad>) getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(SQL_GET_ADS_BY_CURRENT_DATE, Ad.class);
        return query.setParameter(1, currentDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP).getResultList();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Ad> findAds(Filter filter){
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        String findByWord = filter.getDescription();
        System.out.println("FindByWord " + findByWord);

        NativeQuery<Ad> adQuery = (NativeQuery<Ad>) getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(createQuery(filter), Ad.class);
        adQuery.setParameter(2, "%'" + findByWord + "'%");
        adQuery.setParameter(1, currentDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);

        return adQuery.getResultList();
    }

    private String createQuery(Filter filter){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        stringBuilder.append(SQL_GET_ADS_BY_FILTER);

        if (filter.getCategoryType() != null){
            stringBuilder.append(" AND CATEGORY_TYPE = '").append(filter.getCategoryType().toString()).append("'");
        }

        if (filter.getCity() != null){
            stringBuilder.append(" AND CITY = '").append(filter.getCity()).append("'");
        }

        return stringBuilder.append(" ORDER BY DATE_TO DESC").toString();
    }
}
```

Метод получения ста последних объявлений, `get100Ad()`, с учётом даты работает и возвращает найденные объявления. А метод `findAds(Filter filter)` постоянно возвращает пустой список, хотя объекты удовлетворяющие запросу есть в базе.
Подскажите что не так ? В чём у меня ошибка или ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте указать явно имя

```
private static final String SQL_GET_ADS_BY_FILTER = "SELECT * FROM AD WHERE ROWNUM < 101 AND DATE_TO > :date AND AD_DESCRIPTION LIKE :desc";
```

и изменить параметры на (без `'`)

```
adQuery.setParameter("desc", "%" + findByWord + "%");
adQuery.setParameter("date", currentDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
```

И включите (что-то типа `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug`) или добавьте дополнительное логирование, что бы видеть какие запросы на самом деле идут в базу

Comment: Ihar Hulevich, убрал одинарные кавычки, по Вашему совету ... поиск по `description` заработал, но если задаю поиск только по `city` или `categoryType` , то ничего не находится, возвращается пустой список ... и как указать в запросе, чтобы игнорировался регистр символов ?

Comment: @YuriiS Касательно регистра символов, если это обычный SQL - можно попробовать функции типа `UPPER`. Соответственно, `findByWord` заменить на `findByWord.toUpperCase()`

Comment: gooamoko, с `findByWord` особо проблем нет ... по `categoryType` проблема, если в запросе указываю тип прописными символами, то `filter` не мапится, падает ошибка `NPE`, потому что в `Enum`-е  `CategoryType` типы объявления указаны заглавными символами ... ну и самое непонятное сейчас это то, что если в поиске не учавствует поле фильтра `description` то в базе ничего не находится ... метод возвращает пустой список ... как это исправить ?

Comment: gooamoko, я не правильно сказал ... фильтр не мапится, если я в `json` строке пишу `categoryType` прописными символами, когда тестирую в приложении `Postman`